# Joining Two Queries onto a Shared Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been struggling with the concept of combining results of two queries together via a join on a common table and I was hoping I could gain some assistance. The following is a rough guide to the tables:

```
dbo.Asset (not returned in the SELECT statement, used for joins only)
 - dbo.Asset.AssetID
 - dbo.Asset.CatalogueID

dbo.WorkOrder
 - WorkOrderID
 - AssetID
 - WorkOrderNumber

dbo.WorkOrderSpare
 - WorkOrderID
 - WorkOrderSpareID
 - WorkOrderSpareDescription
 - ActualQuantity
 - CreatedDateTime

dbo.Catalogue
 - CatalogueID (PK)
 - CatalogueNumber
 - CatalogueDescription
 - CatalogueGroupID

dbo.CatalogueGroup
 - CatalogueGroupID
 - CatalogueGroupNumber
```

First Query:

```
SELECT CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupName,
    Catalogue.CatalogueNumber,
    Catalogue.CatalogueDescription,
    Catalogue.CatalogueID,
    Asset.IsActive
FROM CatalogueGroup
INNER JOIN Catalogue 
ON CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupID = Catalogue.CatalogueGroupID
INNER JOIN Asset 
ON Catalogue.CatalogueID = Asset.CatalogueID
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber,
    WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderSpareDescription,
    WorkOrderSpare.ActualQuantity,
    WorkOrderSpare.CreatedDateTime
FROM WorkOrder
INNER JOIN WorkOrderSpare
ON WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderID
```

Now I can do the above easily enough in Access (WYSIWYG) by joining Asset/Catalogue/CatalogueGroup together and then joining Asset.AssetID onto WorkOrder.AssetID. I can't seem to get anything similar to work via raw code, I think I have my logic correct for the joins (INNER JOIN on the results of both) but then I am new to this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, any pointers on where I can read further into problems like this would be great.

EDIT: This is what I was trying to use to no avail, I should also mention I am trying to do this in ms-sql, not Access (trying to move away from drag and drop):

```
SELECT CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupName,
    Catalogue.CatalogueNumber,
    Catalogue.CatalogueDescription,
    Catalogue.CatalogueID,
    Asset.IsActive,
    WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderSpareDescription,
    WorkOrderSpare.ActualQuantity,
    WorkOrderSpare.CreatedDateTime,
    WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber
FROM (((CatalogueGroup
INNER JOIN Catalogue 
ON CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupID = Catalogue.CatalogueGroupID)
INNER JOIN Asset ON Catalogue.CatalogueID = Asset.CatalogueID)
INNER JOIN WorkOrderSpare 
ON WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderID)
INNER JOIN WorkOrder ON Asset.AssetID = WorkOrder.AssetID
```

Comment: It might help if you posted the code you're trying to run that isn't working. Seeing your attempt may be worth more than the question as it's currently written. You might be making a very simple mistake that someone could easily spot.

Comment: Also, can't you display the SQL query generated by the WYSIWYG designer in Access? (I don't recall if that's a feature or not. I haven't touched Access in many, many years.)

Comment: Which are the keys you want to use to join the two resultsets? Or, in which way do you want to merge the two resultsets?

Comment: I'll write up the code I was trying to use again and will post it shortly. I was trying to join dbo.Asset.AssetID onto dbo.WorkOrder.AssetID and dbo.Asset.CatalogueID onto dbo.Catalogue.CatalogueID

Comment: There is no `WorkOrder.AssetID` in your table layout. Secondly, this is not Access SQL syntax as Access uses parentheses around multiple INNER JOINs. This must be an SQL Server dialect, especially with `dbo` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I see the issue.  Assuming that the joins themselves are correct (ie your columns do relate to each other), the order of your joins is a little off - when you join WorkOrder to WorkOrderSpare, neither of those two tables relate back to any table you've identified up until that point in the query.  Think of it as joining two tables separately from the chain of joins you have going so far - it's almost like doing two separate join queries.  If you switch the last two it should work, that way WorkOrder will join to Asset (which you've already defined) and then you can join WorkOrderSpare to WorkOrder.  I've also taken the liberty of removing parentheses on the joins, that's an Access thing.

```
SELECT CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupName,
    Catalogue.CatalogueNumber,
    Catalogue.CatalogueDescription,
    Catalogue.CatalogueID,
    Asset.IsActive,
    WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderSpareDescription,
    WorkOrderSpare.ActualQuantity,
    WorkOrderSpare.CreatedDateTime,
    WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber
FROM CatalogueGroup
INNER JOIN Catalogue ON CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupID = Catalogue.CatalogueGroupID
INNER JOIN Asset ON Catalogue.CatalogueID = Asset.CatalogueID
INNER JOIN WorkOrder ON Asset.AssetID = WorkOrder.AssetID
INNER JOIN WorkOrderSpare ON WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderID
```

Comment: @ J.Young If the above answer works for you, do you mind upvoting and accepting?  I tested it out in a mock database and it should work.  I put a fair amount of time into it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close. As a slightly different approach to joining, try this:

```
SELECT CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupName,
  Catalogue.CatalogueNumber,
  Catalogue.CatalogueDescription,
  Catalogue.CatalogueID,
  Asset.IsActive,
  WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderSpareDescription,
  WorkOrderSpare.ActualQuantity,
  WorkOrderSpare.CreatedDateTime,
  WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber
FROM 
  CatalogueGroup, Catalogue, Asset, WorkOrder, WorkOrderSpare
WHERE CatalogueGroup.CatalogueGroupID = Catalogue.CatalogueGroupID
  and Catalogue.CatalogueID = Asset.CatalogueID
  and Asset.AssetID = WorkOrder.AssetID
  and WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderSpare.WorkOrderID
```

It looks like it should work, but not having data, hard to know if simple joins all the way through is what you want. (It's a matter of personal preference whether to use the `and` clauses rather than the inner join syntax. While on style preferences, I like table aliases if supported, so `FROM CatalogueGroup cg` for example, so that you can refer to `cg.CatalogueGroupID` etc, rather than writing out the full table name every time.)

Comment: Nothing happened when I tried that, it is possible that I have the joins incorrect as well, might be best if I do some reading on joins again to ensure my logic is correct!

Comment: it may be the data. it depends what the model is meant to look like. what is the relationship between workOrder and asset (only one asset for each workOrder?) Here is a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d86a/1) that you can play with. If you fill in some realistic data there it may help figure out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. so the error that you noted in a comment

> The multi-part identifier "WorkOrder.WorkOrderID" could not be bound

is usually when you have an alias for a table and instead of using alias in `JOIN` you use the table name or when you are using the wrong column name or table name.

Ideally in SQL server your query should look like this

```
 SELECT 
    cg.CatalogueGroupName, 
    c.CatalogueNumber, 
    c.CatalogueDescription, 
    c.CatalogueID, 
    A.IsActive,
    Wo.WorkOrderNumber,
    WoS.WorkOrderSpareDescription,
    WoS.ActualQuantity,
    WoS.CreatedDateTime
 FROM CatalogueGroup cg 
    INNER JOIN Catalogue c ON cg.CatalogueGroupID = c.CatalogueGroupID
    INNER JOIN Asset A ON c.CatalogueID = A.CatalogueID
    INNER JOIN WorkOrder Wo ON Wo.AssetID= A.AssetID
    INNER JOIN WorkOrderSpare WoS ON Wo.WorkOrderID = WoS.WorkOrderID
```